# Export list of objects with all properties listed in VS2015 Pro while debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I do debugging and have long list of object with a few properties. How to export this list with all properties listed to email from Visual Studio 2015 Professional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already found it:). There is VS extension called Object Exporter. It can be used during debugging to export a value of variable to text (C# code defining this value).

[Details here.](http://www.omarelabd.net/exporting-objects-from-the-visual-studio-debugger)